# javax.el.ELException: Not a Valid Method Expression

Tags: jsp, jsf, el

I'm creating a JSF application. I'm facing the following exception:

> javax.el.ELException: Not a Valid Method Expression

The line it is referring to is the following:

```
<h:commandButton action="#{Login.trylogin} "value="#{messages.click}"/>
```

I also tried `#{Login.trylogin()}`, but the result was the same. The bean behind `#{Login}` has the following method:

```
public String trylogin()
```

In my `faces-config.xml` the navigation case is this one:

```
<navigation-rule>
    <from-view-id>login.jsp</from-view-id>
    <navigation-case>
        <from-action>#{Login.login}</from-action>
        <from-outcome>success</from-outcome>
        <to-view-id>readPW.jsp</to-view-id>
    </navigation-case>
    <navigation-case>
        <from-action>#{Login.login}</from-action>
        <from-outcome>failed</from-outcome>
        <to-view-id>register.jsp</to-view-id> 
    </navigation-case>
```

Note: this is a school project, so I can't use alternative ways for navigation such as implicit navigation.

Comment: is this a typo or it is as is: `action="#{Login.trylogin} "value` space after the `}`  and the `"value` ?

Comment: Is what caused the problem?

Comment: Certainly, whitespace is significant in method expressions.

Comment: yop, that was the reason for the errormessage, it doenst go to the pages it should, but I think that should be fixable, thanks for the help

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems you have just a 'typo' error

```
<h:commandButton action="#{Login.trylogin} "value="#{messages.click}"/><br><br>
```

Fixed version

```
                                          | here    
<h:commandButton action="#{Login.trylogin}" value="#{messages.click}"/><br><br>
```

Comment: @MiguelAngel_LV Glad that I could be of any help :)